# Printing sorted dictionary keys along with sorted values

Tags: python, dictionary

I am sorting a dictionary based on a particular value which is 3rd element on the list(in values) by using:

```
print sorted(dict.keys(), key=lambda k: dict[k][2], reverse=True)[:3]
```

How can I also display the keys to which those sorted values correspond to ?

Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `items` instead of `keys`:

```
print(sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][2], reverse=True)[:3])
```

or save sorted keys, and use that to get items:

```
keys = sorted(dict, key=lambda key: dict[k][2], reverse=True)[:3]
items = [(key, dict[key]) for key in keys]
print(items)
```

if you want values seaparately:

```
keys = sorted(dict, key=lambda k: dict[k][2], reverse=True)[:3]
values = [dict[key] for key in keys]
```

BTW, don't use `dict` as a variable name; it shadows built-in function/type `dict`.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. And I think you mistakenly typed that as k instead of keys(in last block of code). Might want to change that. Cheers!

Comment: @Sherby, You're right. I fixed the code. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the sorted list and print  in format you want.

```
sorted_list = sorted(dict.keys(), key=lambda k: dict[k][2], reverse=True)[:3]
for key in sorted_list:
    print 'key is '+ key + ' value is '+ sorted_list[key][3]
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. However, I get this error in line:   print 'key is '+ key + ' value is '+ sorted_list[key][2]
"TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str"

Comment: I am sorry. I think you should use this line then:
print 'key is '+ key[0] + ' value is '+ key[3]